# How to remove li on click of its child element

Tags: javascript

I am dynamically creating li with javascript, I want to add a close button to each li element created dynamically to delete the li element on click of the close button.This is my code so far:

```
   function addNew(){
    // get value from input field

    var taskName = document.getElementById('task-name').value;


    // innerHTML to be inserted inside li

    var fullText = taskName + '<span class = "close" onclick = 
   "addListener(this)">&times;</span>';


   // calling create function from Element object

   Element.createNew('li','className','tasks',0,fullText);
  }

  // remove function

   function addListener(e){
       e.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode);
   }
```

The problem is the *remove* function removes the last li instead of li being clicked.

Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/amirsaleem/ucuv7hoy/) of the problem.

Comment: the fiddle is working as expected

Comment: Add multiple elements first and then try to remove elements

Comment: i tried that by doing that

Comment: Working fine. What's the issue?

Comment: Yes, working fine. I was inserting the same value again and again. I will reset the input field after submit.
Just curious, why it's behaving unexpectedly when pressing the insert button multiple times?

Answer (score 2):

store all the list items in an array.

```js
//suppose your list items have a class name 'lists'
//create a global var 
var lis = document.getElementsByClassName('lists');
```

initially it'll be empty,
so in your add method(in which you're appending the new list item to ul,
push the new list item in the lists array.

and in the addEvent(e) method , loop around every element in the lists array

```js
function addEvent(e){
for(var i=0; i<lists.length; i++){
if(lists[i] === e){
//remove the lists element by using lists[i] instead of e
// and remember to pop the lists[i] and resize the lists array
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please tell me if my method of creating a new element is acceptable. Or should I refactor it?
See the createNew property of Element Object.

Comment: it can be improved upon.

Comment: nice, all the best